# Slicing hyphenated numbers in Python

Tags: python

I have a python application that produces output statements like EX. "25-32" or "60-100" which represent age groups. These numbers are written to a text file and read from another module. I only need the first number. How would I get ONLY the first number from the output? Like "25" with out the "-32".

```
    with open("output.txt", "r") as f:
        gender = f.readline().split(":")[-1].strip()
        age = f.readline().split(":")[-1].strip()
    print(gender) # Male
    print(age) # 25-32
```

Comment: `age.split('-')[0]`

Comment: `age = f.readline().split(":")[-1].strip().split('-')[0]`?

Comment: How can you understand how to split the line on `:` characters and not realize that you can do the same thing to split the age on `-` characters?

Answer (score 1):

You can still use [split](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) as it can be chained on other [string methods](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#string-methods).

```
In [330]: age = "25-32"

In [331]: age.split("-")
Out[331]: ['25', '32']

In [332]: age.split("-")[0]
Out[332]: '25'
```

So edit this line:

```
age = f.readline().split(":")[-1].strip().split('-')[0]
```